# How to edit SQL error generated by PDO.php?

Tags: magento-1.7, php, mysql, sql

I started with **this exception**:

```
exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1' in /var/www/vhosts/ourdomain.com/httpdocs/lib/Zend/Db/Statement/Pdo.php:236
```

Used **Mysql.php** to log SQL to **pdo_mysql.log**

Found this in the log:

```
SQL: SELECT `catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)
```

**Ran**

```
SELECT `catalog_category_entity`.* FROM `catalog_category_entity` WHERE (entity_id =)
```

as a query in the database.

**Received:**

```
1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ') LIMIT 0, 30' at line 1
```

So this is the cause of the exception.
How do I go about identifying what generates this SQL, and then edit/fix it?

Edit (further info):
So entity_id = without the other side of the equation is wrong.

Stack log #10 `/var/www/vhosts/ourdomain.com/httpdocs/app/code/core/Mage/Catalog/Block/Product/List.php(80): Mage_Core_Model_Abstract->load(Object(Mage_Catalog_Model_Category))`

is:

```
$category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly the `) LIMIT 0, 30` part of the error is likely because you ran the query in PHPMyAdmin which automatically adds that limit clause.

The error here is that `(entity_id=)` is not valid SQL. SQL expects an [integer or a quoted string to follow the comparison operator](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_equal). So the real question here is how PDO managed to funge this up.

Being that the query that seems to generate this error is `SELECT catalog_category_entity.*` I believe this to be custom code attempting to incorrectly execute the following statement:

```
Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load([id]);
```

I have tried to replicate this and cannot. There are a number of places where categories are being loaded natively in Magento, so I would venture to say this is an error from custom code which is extending/overwriting `Mage_Core_Model_Abstract`.

Disable all local modules which rewrite that class and see if the issue persists. If not, follow the [standard Magento debugging process](https://www.sonassi.com/knowledge-base/magento-debug-process/) and report back.

Comment: thanks - I can see $category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($this->getCategoryId());  -  would you suggest changing to your example?

Comment: Try calling Mage::log($this->getCategoryId()); prior to that line and see what it returns. If it's null, false, or another object that load statement won't work as you're expecting it to and I suggest the next bit of functionality would be to guard code from executing assuming $category is populated. Please follow the standard debug process as linked above and report back with your findings.